# Notification service architecture

Tags: mongodb, redis, architecture, notifications, queue

I am currently trying to write a notification system for chat rooms. I have several types of notifications: push, email, sms. I'm faced with the following problem, what architecture to choose for such a system, as well as the data storage for the notifications. My options at the moment are:

1. The notification will go to Notification service, where all new notifications will be added to the queue, every second data from this queue will be written to mongodb in packets. Every tick, that is a second the background process will run batch processing, to retrieve data from the database. How I plan to retrieve data, it's simple the entity will specify a deadline field, and if deadline is less than or equal to current time then I retrieve such a task, process it and pass to pub/sub by chunks. Further delivery service will just distribute data in packets to different services, which are directly responsible for sending certain types of messages.
   Pros: in future I will need delayed sending notification, and the logic will not change in any way, simple solution.
   Cons: every second I need to query mongodb, because of the fact that the pushes to notify about the events in the chats, when the event comes for example "user a wrote you a message", then I know chatid, and must notice the old notice on the new, it means I need to use upsert, like this does not impose me a penalty, unless I update the fields that are indexed, also a lot of data to paste. The more data there is in the database, the harder it is to sample
2. Create a queue in redis for each type of notification. Except that to speed up sampling, you need to use several queues. One stores the id of the task and its execution time, and the second stores the payload. So we have one general queue, and one for each type of notifications. That makes 4 queues. Then the processing remains the same, pus/sub on redis, delivery service and so on.
   Pros: speed of redis, ability to insert a lot of data with pipeline packets.
   Cons: you have to create a separate queue for each type, and a common one for management.
3. Add priorities, when the task is added, then by the type of priority, it can be saved in redis if it is a high priority, if medium or low then in mongodb, sampling remains the same, except that perhaps with each addition we should look for the minimum deadline value, and this is int64 and if the deadline of new task is less than the previous deadline (which we also found), in this case you should change the time of call of background batch processing.
   Disadvantages: we need task scheduler, adapt batch processing for sampling from multiple storages.
   Pros: resource allocation, fewer database queries, task scheduling only.

I would also add that all tasks that add to notifications, can not be completed earlier than 10 seconds, this is done to cancel the sending of the reason if the message read, the person has logged into the application and there is no point in sending mailing events that took place without him

My problem, is that out of all these options I can not choose the right one, although I have tried 1, 2 already implemented, and add load

Maybe I'm missing something, and let's say queries every second in mongodb are normal. But at the same time I don't want to build the system too complex and redundant